# Ubuntu Cannot reinstall coreutils

Tags: npm, ubuntu-16.04

I deleted the `usr/bin/env` directory/file in my Ubuntu16.04 by mistake. Everytime i try to reinstall coreutils with this command:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils`, i get this error:
`Reinstallation of coreutils is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.`

I can't use npm because it needs that directory.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by manually getting the env file from the coreutils package i downloaded from the Ubuntu site and replacing where i deleted it.